# Как добавить двойную цену, за литр и мл?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, плагин, wp-plugin

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать двойную цену у товаров. Есть сайт по продаже духов, и по закону нужно указывать цену за литр, как вот здесь[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть, может, какой-то плагин или хук. Понимаю, что можно через кастомные поля, но хотелось бы как можно проще.

Если кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей и может помочь, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Если цена флаконов не пропорциональна цене за литр, и берется из внешних источников (базы поставщика например), то самое простое - произвольное поле.